# having multiple mvc projects under same url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if it's possible to create an mvc project with layers inside or even multiple projects using the same web address.

Like if I have a website called mysite.com which have a website project doing sine stuff.

But then I have a webproject which I'm doing some experimentational code on which I whould like to find via the url "mysite.com/test". This whold be a dufferent mvc project. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, what you actually need to is create a new project and define it inside a virtual directory.

MVC is based on global.asax and web.config configurations and you can't have 2 separate projects inside the same application. In the scenario you described, it sounds like you need to create a "Virtual Directory" in IIS for the second application instead of making just a "Sub Folder".

The Virtual Directory will allow you to declare a new web.config and global.asax where you set the new routings and configurations method for your second application and this will also give you the freedom for independent updates without affecting your main project.

For a full walkthrough on how you can perform this please refer to this site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763173(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I can't change anything on the server, only in the project that I upload. Will this solution still be valid then, 'cause I don't seem to be able to get it to work